# How to PREPEND rules rather than APPEND using iptables?

Tags: networking, firewall, iptables

Pretty basic question: how to PREPEND rules on IPTABLES rather than to APPEND?

I have `DROP` statements at the bottom of my rules.  I have a software to add new rules but adding rules after `DROP` statements isn't good.  Every time I want to add a new rule, I have to flush the table (which is inefficient).

Is there a way to prepend a rule i.e., add a rule to the top of the table rather than the bottom?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Use the `-I` switch:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT 1 -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

This would insert a rule at position #1 in the INPUT chain.

Comment: Dang! You beat me by 18 seconds... I wasn't quick enough :(

Comment: Hehehehehehehe :)

Comment: @YanickGirourad, hah, you got the checkmark!

Comment: Also to note, when using -I INPUT 1, no rule gets overwritten. Instead all rules will be shifted by one position up.

Comment: Important note from Abdull.

Comment: The `1` isn't even required, per the man page: _If the  rule  number is  1,  the  rule  or rules are inserted at the head of the chain.  This is also the default if no rule number is specified._

Answer (score 23):

`-I` will insert.  You're probably using `-A` to append.

You can also do `iptables -I chain rulenum` to insert a rule as number "rulenum" in chain "chain".  `-R chain rulenum` can be used to replace a specific rule at number "rulenum" in chain "chain".  `iptables -L -n --line-numbers` will show the rule numbers in the left-most column.

Comment: I'm in a rush at the moment or I'd look it up but it would be nice to see an example of how the "chain" works here, or a link.

Comment: // , Refer to https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_edit_iptables_rules#Inserting_Rules for more information about how to correctly insert an IPTables rule.

Answer (score 2):

To help with determining what line number to add the new rule, I use `iptables-save` to output the existing rules to the console.

For beginners I can also suggest a cheat card by using webmin administer your rules.  It's very friendly and you can easily manually re-order rules in the list.  It will also handle the 'slight' variations in redhat vs debian based implementations of iptables.

Comment: `iptables -L --line-numbers` is a little more platform independant

Comment: I'm not sure exactly why one should use webmin for that (or anything).  It's far better to learn the command-line way than to use a crutch.

Answer (score 2):

There is a program named `iptables-persistent` which make iptable's rules persistent as a OS service. this service include a configuration file as the `iptables-save` export.

So you can reorder the lines in the configuration file and restart the service.

```
sudo service iptables-persistent restart
```

So easy!!!!!